Subjective confidence as weights in regression models
I have data where subjects rate a quantity on a certain scale ($y$) but also add their subjective confidence as to how sure they are in their choice ($w$). My initial thought was to add $w$ as weights to the regression models (disregard the question of how to normalize or standardize them for now). My superior asked to check the relation between the $w$ to the variance - stating that incorporating confidence should be done if they are inversely proportional to the variance. We checked the mean absolute residual from the non-weighted model (as a proxy for the variance) and saw that higher confidence had about the same residuals as the lower ones. My superior concluded that we should not use the confidence ratings.
While I do agree that the data and the model don't seem to show that higher confidence ratings relate to lower variance, I'm still not convinced that this is the only reason to use weights. If there is great confidence in certain data points, shouldn't they get more say in pulling the regression line to pass closer to them, than other data points which had less confidence?

I may well agree with you, however I think that it'll depend on what exact use you want to make of the regression, and/or what kind of interpretation you have in mind for the result. Can you explain a bit more about this? I may then write an answer. It may also depend on what the scale of $w$ is and how it was introduced to the raters.

I would agree with your professor that it is the only reason.
The issue is that you have no proof that their confidence is well placed.
It's possible that using a weighted model might give you different residuals and so align with the claim that high confidence regions have lower variance.  However, you don't really know
a) what is the right transform from confidence to weightings (linear/sqrt/..)
b) how do you identify to what extent the lower residual is due to the 'imposed' weighting rather than a natural consequence of the 'correct' weighting.
The residuals should scale with the weighting (ie $\text{residual}^2  \propto  \frac{1}{\text{w}}$), so if you find that the residuals are reduced by more than this, then this would be evidence that the weighting is correct.
However all this requires investigation, and I assume you have not enough data to consider different weightings without p-hacking.  So I feel that you should keep to your professor's suggestion.

Thanks for answering. I will see if there are any other replies before accepting it.

If the weightings were indeed "correct", why would residuals from an unweighted (i.e., "incorrect") regression be informative about this? (I should add that I don't think that there are unique "objectively correct" weightings in such a situation, and I don't think trying to assess the "correctness" of the weightings from the data alone solves this problem comprehensively.)
